# Timepicker not showing on focus with dynamic entries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scheduler that allows a user to pick times. Using Ajax each row for a schedule time is appended, in that row they can select date, start time and end time. The datepicker seems to work but the timepicker is not showing up.

I tried using `document` instead of `body` for the selector in my jquery but didn't work.

`$(document).on('focus', ".timepickerInput", function () {
                    $(this).timepicker({
                        timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
                        interval: 5,
                        dropdown: true,
                        scrollbar: true
                    });
                });`

Datepicker:

```
$('body').on('focus', ".datepickerInput", function () {
                    $(this).datepicker({
                        controlType: "select",

                    });
                });
```

Here is the code for the current timepicker:

```
$('body').on('focus', ".timepickerInput", function () {
                    $(this).timepicker({
                        timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
                        interval: 5,
                        dropdown: true,
                        scrollbar: true
                    });
                });
```

Here is the code for adding a new row:

```
$("#addScheduleButton").click(function () {
                    var nextIndex = $(".pendingScheduleRow").length;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Admin/AddScheduleItem",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            index: nextIndex
                        },
                        success: function (results) {
                            $("table#scheduleTable tbody").append(results);
                            $("#savePendingButton").show();
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Here is the HTML form:

```
<form asp-action="SetSchedule" asp-controller="Admin" method="post" id="addEventForm">
                <table id="scheduleTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Start Time</th>
                            <th>End Time</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>

                <br />
                <button id="addScheduleButton" type="button">Add Schedule Time</button>
                <button id="savePendingButton" type="submit" style="margin-left:1em" hidden>Save</button>
            </form>
```

I would like the timepicker to work for every row that is added when it is dynamically appended to the html.

Comment: Do you have a datepicker also? what is timepicker? a jquery plugin? you are just converting an input field into timepicker on every time it gets focused but without knowing what or how the timepicker works it is difficult to tell what is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I added the datepicker to the question. Yeah, the timepicker is jquery.